# Adding a column requires a default value for another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, alter

I'm adding a column to a table, but it tells me I'm not setting a default value for another column of the table;

```
ALTER TABLE `myDatabase`.`myTable` ADD myNewColumn varchar(2);
```

Gives me the response

`ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'modifiedDate'`

I don't get why I need to set a default value for a column when I'm just altering a table?

Comment: Does modifiedDate allow null values?

Comment: put ur table creation sql here

Comment: Your statement is one row, but you get an error indicating there's a 5th row...

Comment: what is your table structure?

Comment: The error is not on this ALTER, but on the previous CREATE TABLE.

Comment: The table had modifiedDate default set as 0000-00-00 00:00:00
I decided to modify this to be CURRENT_TIMESTAMP then the script worked
@jarlh I ran it once from the full script, the isolated the line itself and got a similar message, I updated the error message for when I just run that one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my table definition, not the command itself.

The table had modifiedDate set incorrectly I assume, I changed it to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead with the following command

`ALTER TABLE myTable MODIFY column modifiedDate timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

After this everything worked. Below is the description of this row before:

`| Field       | Type      | Null| Key | Default

| modifiedDate | timestamp | NO  |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00`

And after :

`| Field       | Type      | Null| Key | Default

| modifiedDate | timestamp | NO  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`